# Blazor Shared UI Toaster Component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am just getting up to speed on Server side Blazor (not webassembly), so forgive me if this is a silly question.

What I am trying to do is have service which can be used to display a toast.  The component Library I am using is from Syncfusion.  I can use this just fine in the usual way where it is embedded on each component where it is needed.

```
<SfToast ID="toast_default" @ref="Toaster" CssClass="e-toast-success" content="@ViewModel.ToastMessage" Timeout="2000" Icon="e-meeting">
     <ToastPosition X="Right" ></ToastPosition>
</SfToast>
```

I can use this in the code behind and it displays a toast as expected.

But I have many pages that use this code and would like to not repeat myself.  I would like to be able to use the above once in app.razor, and then get a reference to it, and then it throughout the app.  For example, in the `onIntializedAsync`, I get a reference to the Toaster, save it to an injected service.  Then I use the same service throughout the app.

I coded the above, but Toaster is always null in the service.

```
    public class MessageService
    {
        public SfToast Toaster { get; set; }

        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            if(this.Toaster!= null)
            {
                await this.Toaster.Show(new ToastModel() { Content = message });
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code in App.razor. I have stepped through the code and it sets the reference to Toaster correctly, but when the message service tries to get it to use it, it is null.

```
@code {

    public SfToast Toaster { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.MessageService.Toaster = this.Toaster;
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Is there another way to do this?  Or am I making some mistake?

Comment: I inject a scoped service. This service has `ShowMessage` method. My `SfToast` is only on main layout. Main layout sets a delegate to scoped service, this delegate is able to show messages through toast. When you say to scoped service to show a message, it uses this delegate.

Comment: the easiest way is to use a CascadeParameter

Comment: @nAviD, Thank you, I think you are right.  If you want to post as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: @daniherrera, I am not sure what you mean by "Main layout sets a delegate". Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `CascadeParameter`.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @nAviD's answer, I did this:

`MainLayout.razor` sets up the cascading parameter. The toaster components sets a @ref in the MessageService.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using JusticeOnTheWeb.Core

<CascadingValue Value="MessageService">
    <div class="content">
        @Body
    </div>
</CascadingValue>

<SfToast ID="toast_default" @ref="MessageService.Toaster" CssClass="e-toast-success" Timeout="2000" Icon="e-meeting">
    <ToastPosition X="Right"></ToastPosition>
</SfToast>

@code{

    public MessageService MessageService { get; set; } = new MessageService();

}
```

Then it gets consumed by `MyComponent.razor`:

```
<SfButton @onclick="ShowMessage">Show Message</SfButton>


@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    public MessageService MessageService { get; set; }

    public void ShowMessage()
    {
        this.MessageService.Show("42");
    }
}
```